# Where is the file saved by Cordova File plugin on iOS

Tags: ios, file, cordova, ionic-framework

I am writing a PDF file on an iPhone running iOS 11, using [Cordova File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) (in Ionic). The file is created successfully (e.g. in a location like `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CDFC4E19-082F-4878-9168-F4A735CDAFEB/Documents` or `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DA918690-B345-438A-B26D-2EA21D618341/Library/Cloud`), but then I can't find the file on the iPhone. I have tried setting the directory to `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` as well as `cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory`. When I run the Files app on the iPhone, it shows no recent documents, nor any documents at all. I can't find the file on the phone to view it outside of my app.

Where do I have to save the file to make it findable outside of the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've answered this myself. Viewing a PDF that an app created is just not a thing on iOS, as useful as that may be. You can of course do that on Android, which is far more useful. It appears that to view the PDF, you have to use iTunes on an iMac to download the file from the phone. Jumping through those Apple hoops, which I am slowly becoming accustomed to, I was able to view the file in the `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` location.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` the files will be saved in the [appPath]/Documents, but this path is internal and not accessible for normal users. You have to add these keys in the `info.plist` file, to show the files in the iPhone file explorer:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

With these keys, the OS will show the internal files in the mobile Explorer. In fact, the files shown are symlinks to the original files, located in the app folder.
You could find more info [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/560#issuecomment-1457359007).